# $(window).height() and window.innerHeight don't give the same output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 2.1.1. When I type `window.innerHeight` and `$(window).height()` in browser console, they don't give the same output. Please refer to the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I am not able to figure out what is happening. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not reproducing on this page.

Comment: I just tested but having same value..

Comment: This is not happening on this page. This is happening on one page, I have on my local machine.

Comment: Can you give jsFiddle example?

Comment: Actually this does happen in this page here, too. If you draw the browser window rather small. My guess is that it got to do with overflows and scrollbars or something like that.

Comment: @Avisho: Here http://jsfiddle.net/byhLn37b/1/

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem...

This is all because of the browser console window.

if you close the console window and run below you'll see that the height statements are the same.

```
<script>
alert(window.innerHeight);
alert($(window).height());
</script>
```

It seems that `window.innerHeight` calculates the height of the browser without the console window height.

Comment: If you open console on this page and run the same commands, they give the same output.

Comment: of course, because it reduce the console page height... this is all due to the console page. if you run my code without console page the values will be the same.

Comment: Screenshot of? You can verify it by adding one more paragraph in the HTML file.

Comment: The screenshot is to see how you check the values.